# How to create brush in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, brush, calligraphy

I have been trying to create this type of brush in Adobe Illustrator. This brush was created in Procreate but I am trying to get the same effect but in Illustrator instead.

The bottom image is the brush I am trying to create. The image above is my failed attempt at creating the brush.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you can get there with a simple straightforward **Art Brush**.  But the angle of the brush shouldn't be "built in" to the settings. A straight brush is created, then the angle of the brushstroke is controlled by the path it's on.

Two simple rectangles, dragged to Brushes and an **Art Brush** created. The brush is applied to the path on the right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice Scott. Is there any way I could have the brush turned at a 35º angle though?

Comment: I'm afraid if you need that degree of control, a brush may not work for whatever you are doing. At least not an Illustrator brush. I can't think of any method to create a 35° brush and maintain that "gap" appearance. That, obviously, doesn't mean one does NOT exist.. but I'm simply unaware of any brush or brush options that would work.

Comment: The only way I can think of to set a brush at a specific angle is via a Scatter brush, but that's [not going to give great results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii4Yx.png). Scatter brushes aren't "aware" of their artwork in terms of blending. they merely place iterations of the artwork at the angle.